# (Angular) Using jQuery (or pure JS) to check specific mat-slide-toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material, in this specific case, the `<mat-slide-toggle'>` tag, inside a *ngFor. As the page loads, its accessing my db to see which should be checked and which shouldn't. A very small amount of them should (something around 20%), so they are, by default, unchecked.

When my API returns the database response, Angular must get the ID's of the toggles that must be checked, and check them. I'm using this logic to check some checkboxes, and it works, but with `<mat-slide-toggle>`, jQuery does not seem to interact.

This is how I'm doing it:

The sliders:

```
<div id="table" *ngFor="let data of User; let i = index">
      <mat-slide-toggle  
      disabled
      [id]='data.code15'
      (change)=toggle(data.code15)
      color=primary 
      class="status">Active
      </mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

The logic that should check them (this i guarantee 100% that its working, it just can't check them, but it can console.log their ID's accordingly):

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < this.IntArray.length ; i++){
  if(this.IntArray[i].status == 0){
    console.log("Toggle's ID: " + $("#"+this.IntArray[i].user.toString()).attr('id')); 
    //this is the correct console log
    $("#"+this.IntArray[i].code15.toString()).prop('checked', true); 
    //this should check them (code15 is the ID of each toggle)
  }
}
```

The problem here is that somehow to toggle does not respond to the jQuery command (while my checkboxes do, with a very similar logic). I can't get the toggles to check. Is there any other way?

By the way, the problem of using `<mat-slide-toggle [checked]=foo>` is that the global variable 'foo' will not receive any value, as the page takes at least half a second to get a response from the database (which is quite full).

I'm out of options here, I really need the toggle, as it is way more 'user-friendly' and stylish than radio buttons, as well as easier to deal with in CSS.

Any tips? jQuery or JS accepted...

Comment: I would take a bet that ngFor is in wrong element

Comment: nope, the ngFor is where it should

Comment: So if User has length 10 you have 10 divs with id="table" ??

Comment: Yes, that is for CSS, because i want all divs with id 'table' to follow a pattern, and not all the divs 'table' are inside this ngFor. But this does not affect my slide-toggle

Comment: Id's should be unique. Use name or a class. As for the issue. have you tried setting [checked] to a property of User object? this would automatically change the slide when the object changes. DO NOT USE JQUERY.

Comment: Yes, it does not work, as the status is not a boolean in the db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186112/discussion-between-itdoesntwork-and-ch4b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to accomplish this... this would be Angular/JS and not jQuery

> I do not know the format of your data coming back from db so I did a simple mock array for demonstration purposes.

I assume there is some value in your array from db that determines if slider should be checked... here I just use a boolean with key of `checked`

```
 User = [
    { id: 1, checked: true },
    { id: 2, checked: false },
    { id: 3, checked: false },
    { id: 4, checked: true },
    { id: 5, checked: false },
    { id: 6, checked: false },
  ]
```

I then use `@ViewChildren` to get all the sliders on the DOM

```
import { MatSlideToggle } from '@angular/material'
@ViewChildren(MatSlideToggle) toggleArray
```

After `ViewInit` loop through the array of sliders on the DOM and compare them to the `User` array and set the ones that need to be checked.

> I am setting sliders to `checked` after `ViewInit` here, you could execute this logic when the response comes back from DB and it will work the same.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.toggleArray.toArray().forEach((el) => {
      let i = this.User.findIndex(u => el.id == u.id)
      if (this.User[i].checked) {
        el.checked = true;
      }
    })
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idbj9c?embed=1&file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.ts